# Translating domain\username into a SID?

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm using bellow code to translate `DOMAIN\USERNAME` into a SID

```
$NTAccount = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($ComputerName, $User)
$AccountSID = $NTAccount.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).ToString()
```

Where variables `ComputerName` and `$User` in above code are for example:

1. `Users\SomeUser`
2. `NT AUTHORITY\ SYSTEM`
3. `BUILTIN\Administrators`

And this works just fine, however it fails with following:

1. `APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES`
2. `APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\Your Internet connection`

What modifications or classes do I need to translate `APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY` into a SID? for example above 2 samples.

Well known SID enum does not help, I need specific `APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY` SID value.

**EDIT:**

In any case I tried this (just because I have no options left):

```
$AccountSID = [System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType]::WinBuiltinAnyPackageSid
```

Perfectly valid code acording to documentation and it doesn't work!

> The property 'WinBuiltinAnyPackageSid' cannot be found on this object.
>   Verify that the property exists

Comment: Not absolutely sure, but I think the SID for `APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES` is `S-1-15-2-1`, and the one with limitations is `S-1-15-2-2`. (found info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/81d92bba-d22b-4a8c-908a-554ab29148ab?redirectedfrom=MSDN))

Comment: Thanks, but I needed this to be known at "run" time.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem with following command:

```
$NTAccount = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($User)
$AccountSID = $NTAccount.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).ToString()
```

The difference is that no domain name is supplied to `NTAccount` constructor, which is needed if you want SID for any `APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\...`

This constructor will correctly resolve name and give exact SID!

For example:

```
$NTAccount = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Your Internet connection")
$AccountSID = $NTAccount.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).ToString()
$AccountSID
```

Conclusion is, in any case if providing domain name (built in or not) if it doesn't work, just omit domain name and that's it!

Comment: Is this a local user ? If yes, then use just `Get-LocalUser login | Select -Property SID`

Comment: @krokodilko no, `APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY` isn't local user, but thank you for comment, it's useful for local users.